# Elements inside CardView don't have a ripple effect

Tags: android, android-cardview

I know I can add a ripple effect to CardView itself in the following way:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

The problem is how can I do it with CheckBox or RadioButton which are placed inside CardView? 
I have a ripple effect around CheckBox in others app's places. 
It's seems like CardView removes this effect from their children.

Comment: delegate touch events from buttons to the card

Comment: @Chisko nice idea, but in my case CardView already has OnClickListener for another purpose. There are should be two listeners, one for CheckBox and one for CardView and both with a ripple effect.